# How to create a condition with two inputs with date?

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, input

can you please help me with someone with the data boxes?

I have two data boxes.
I would need to somehow create a condition in PHP or JavaScript so that the date2 field is always higher than date1.

If the condition were violated, the date2 field would be automatically set to the same date as in date1.

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="vypocet();ubytko_single();ubytko_double();" onkeydown="return false" id="datumprijezdu" name="datumprijezdu" min="<?php echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'); ?>" value="<?php echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
       <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="datumprijezdu">Datum příjezdu</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="DateCheck();vypocet();ubytko_single();ubytko_double();" onkeydown="return false" id="datumodjezdu" name="datumodjezdu" value="<?php echo (new DateTime('tomorrow'))->format('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo (new DateTime('tomorrow'))->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
       <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="datumodjezdu">Datum odjezdu</label>
     </div>
```

JS

```js
function vypocet() {
const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  const utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  const utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}

// test it
var x = document.getElementById("datumprijezdu");
var datumprijezdu = x.value;
var y = document.getElementById("datumodjezdu");
var datumodjezdu = y.value;
const a = new Date(datumprijezdu);
    b = new Date(datumodjezdu),
    pocet_dnu = dateDiffInDays(a, b);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pocet_dnu;
}

function ubytko_single() {
var ubytko_single_vysledek=0;
var ubytko_single_vysledek = pocet_dnu * 1980;
    document.getElementById("ubytko_single_vysledek").innerHTML = ubytko_single_vysledek + "CZK při možnosti single";
}

function ubytko_double() {
var ubytko_double_vysledek=0;
var ubytko_double_vysledek = pocet_dnu * 2260;
    document.getElementById("ubytko_double_vysledek").innerHTML = ubytko_double_vysledek + "CZK při možnosti double";
}
```

I tried searching on the internet, but the scripts found didn't work for me: /

Comment: Do you have any code we can use as a scaffold?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the HTML code. I've also added features that the HTML code calls. However, the function is somehow unrelated to the topic of this post. I therefore inserted them if someone thought of inserting a function into existing functions.

Comment: Only post minimum code to replicate or demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic implementation that you can use. :)

If you have details, I can edit my answer.

```js
var date1 = document.getElementById("date1");
var date2 = document.getElementById("date2");

function dateChecker()
{
  if (date1.valueAsDate > date2.valueAsDate)
  {
    
    date2.value = date1.value;
  } else
  {
    console.log("Dates are fine");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date1">Date 1</input>
<br>
<input type="date" id="date2">Date 2</input>
<br>
<button id="submit" onClick="dateChecker()">Check Dates</button>
```

Comment: The OP says: "*If the condition were violated, the date2 field would be automatically set to the same date as in date1.*" Swapping the values in the UI is not a good idea. Since the values are strings (and roughly ISO 8601), it would be better to use [*localeCompare*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: I misread. I thought it was to swap. If it's being fed into another function, it'd be even easier to just put a conditional. He added stuff since my answer.

Comment: If anything, you can just use .valueAsDate, and I've edited the logic to conform to both. Thanks for the input!